# Error de solicitud POST con JSON con acentos en Android

Tags: java, android, asp.net, json

Estoy enviando una solicitud a un API en ASP.NET desde Android, estoy utilizando Spring Framework para hacer las solicitudes, el problema es que al enviar un JSON que contenga caracteres acentuados el servidor retorna una excepción con el siguiente mensaje:

```
{"exception":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
```

El problema sólo se da con los acentos, y desde la app Android, he enviado el una solicitud idéntica (con acentos) utilizando Postman, y el servidor la acepta sin problemas.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando en Java:

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
JSONObject request = new JSONObject()
                    .put("Title", "título")
                    .put("Content", "contenido del mensaje");

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(request.toString(), headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = rest.exchange("http://elsitio.com/message/post?authToken={authToken}", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class, Session.getToken());
```

Ya he intentado cambiando el idioma del servidor y no da resultados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba añadiendo conversión a UTF-8 (o el encoding que necesites):

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
rest .getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```